# Unable to read file on Databricks spark python notebook, IO error

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am a new user to spark, and am using python notebook. I uploaded a file on the cluster which does show up when I run the command

```
display(dbutils.fs.ls("/"))
```

The  location of the file which I want to read shows up as dbfs:/YGS1.txt. However when I call the file using

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('/YGS1.txt')
```

I get an error saying "IOError: File /YGS1.txt does not exist" . I have also tried using

```
df=pd.read_csv('dbfs:/YGS1.txt')
```

and I still get an error saying "IOError: File dbfs:/YGS1.txt does not exist".
I just want to load the file into the dataframe using existing python libraries. Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: This is probably best solved in the databricks community forums since DBFS is not currently an open source (or even publicly accesiable) component.

Comment: Thanks Holden, I have posted the same there too :)

Comment: Just realized it is the problem with trying to open with pandas. Since pandas are unaware of the spark context and the data base type of dbfs, an IO error is given. When I use
    sc.textFile("dbfs:/YGS1.txt")

it is able to find the file